# Options won't load in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

For some reason al my options will not be shown in the chart. Can't find the error myself. The code of the chart is a snippet from this code: https://codepen.io/sietssoo/pen/oNqGpXq
If anyone could find the error, you would be my hero.

```
  //Making chart
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: getChartData(),
    options: {
      legend: {display: true},
      responsive: true,
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        callbacks: {
          label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
            return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + '€ ' + tooltipItem.yLabel;
          }
        }
      },
      scales: {
        x: [{
          stacked: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            isplay: true,
            labelString: 'Jaar'
          }
        }],
        y: [{
          stacked: true,
          scaleLabel: {display: true},
          ticks: {
            callback: function (value) {
              return '€' + value;
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: The current version of Chart.js is 3.8.2, while, by the way the options are laid out in your snippet, it looks like the codeped used v2. What version are you using? A lot of configuration options got moved around in v3, so I suggest you take a look at the official website: for example, the `tooltip` key now goes into a new property `plugins` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using V2 syntax in V3.

the legend and tooltip config have been moved to the `options.plugins.legend` and `options.plugins.tooltip` namespace, the scales are not arrays anymore all scales are their own object.

For all the changes and detailed explanation you can read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.0/getting-started/v3-migration.html)